# sort vector of struct element

Tags: c++, stl

i am trying to  sort vector  of struct's elements,but i can't construct  vector itself here is code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct student_t{
      string name;
  int age,score;
}   ;

bool compare(student_t const &lhs,student_t const &rhs){
    if (lhs.name<rhs.name)
         return true;
    else if (rhs.name<lhs.name)
        return false;

    else
        if (lhs.age<rhs.age)
            return true;
        else if (rhs.age<lhs.age)
             return false;
    return lhs.score<rhs.score;

}
int main(){

               struct student_t st[10];







 return 0;
}
```

when i declared  `vector<student_t>st`  i can't  access  element of struct,please give me hint how to do it

Comment: **PLEASE** put {braces} when using `if` blocks. Relying on indentation when writing `if` blocks is **dangerous**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<student_t> st;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) st.push_back(student_t());
std::sort(st.begin(), st.end(), &compare);
```

You could also use this `vector` constructor instead of lines 1-2:

```
std::vector<student_t> st (10 /*, student_t() */);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to enter 10 students with the keyboard you can write a function that constructs a student:

```
struct student_t &enter_student()
{
     student_t s;
     std::cout << "Enter name" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> s.name;
     std::cout << "Enter age" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> s.age;
     std::cout << "Enter score" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> s.score;
     return s;
}
std::vector<student_t> st;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) st.push_back(enter_student());
```

Comment: @user466534: edited answer. Maybe you should read a book about the STL.

Answer (score 0):

to sort the vector:

```
sort(st.begin(), st.end(), compare);
```

and to read input to your vector you should first resize the vector or input to a temporary
variable and push it to your vector:

[www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)