# C++ sorting a vector of objects, getting error C3867 function call missing argument list?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm currently writing a program to detect license plate text.  I have a class PossiblePlate with member variables, at one point in main I would like to sort a vector of PossiblePlate objects in descending order by the number of characters detected in the plate, which is in the member variable strChars.  Here is the relevant code:

in main:

```
std::sort(vectorOfPossiblePlates.begin(), vectorOfPossiblePlates.end(), PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars);
```

PossiblePlate.h (so far, I'm probably going to add more):

```
// PossiblePlate.h

#ifndef POSSIBLEPLATE_H
#define POSSIBLEPLATE_H

#include <string>

#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PossiblePlate {
public:
    // member variables ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cv::Mat imgPlate;
    cv::Mat imgGrayscale;
    cv::Mat imgThresh;

    std::vector<cv::RotatedRect> locationOfPlateInScene;

    std::string strChars;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    bool sortDescendingByNumberOfChars(const PossiblePlate &ppLeft, const PossiblePlate &ppRight);

};

#endif      // end #ifndef POSSIBLEPLATE_H
```

here is PossiblePlate.cpp (so far, I may add more)

```
// PossiblePlate.cpp

#include "PossiblePlate.h"


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool sortDescendingByNumberOfChars(const PossiblePlate &ppLeft, const PossiblePlate &ppRight) {
    return(ppLeft.strChars.length() < ppRight.strChars.length());
}
```

When I run this with Visual Studio 2013 I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars': function call missing argument list; use '&PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars' to create a pointer to member c:\visualstudio2013progs\cpp\licenseplaterecognition1\main.cpp  44  1   LicensePlateRecognition
```

Line 44 in main is the line in main above that calls std::sort.

I've done the same thing in other programs before without a problem.  Everything I'm doing here is consistent with how I have done this in the past and with other Stack Overflow posts such as these:

[sorting a vector of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892680/sorting-a-vector-of-structs)

[sort vector of struct element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632034/sort-vector-of-struct-element)

[Sorting a vector of objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102246/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-in-c)

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm at a loss here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in the posted code.

First, the function passed to `std::sort` has to be callable with two arguments of the type being sorted. `PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars` is a non-static member function, so it has to be called on an object of type `PossiblePlate`, with two additional arguments. `std::sort` can't cope with that. Make it a static member function.

Second, PossiblePlate.cpp defines a free function named `sortDescendingByNumberOfChars`; that's okay, but it's not the member function. Change its declaration from `sortDescendingByNumberOfChars` to `PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars` to define the member function.

Third, follow the advice in the error message. To take the address of a member function, the correct syntax is `&ClassName::FunctionName`. The call in the code does not have the `&`.

Comment: As answered, std::sort won't work with non-static member functions. Alternatives to using a static function are a lambda function or a functor (function operator).

Comment: @rcgldr - or with a free function, like the one defined in PossiblePlate.cpp. But that's not what this question is about.

Comment: I just wanted to warn the OP about the potential issue and alternatives.